# Determining the VA needed for a transformer, when I know the power DC

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer

I am attempting to design and build my own power supply.  I would like to be able to get ~50VDC, and ~ 5A out of it at max load.

Unfortunately, I'm a little lost when it comes to understanding power transformers.  I understand that VA does not equal Watts, and I understand that 36Vrms is ~ 51VDC (which, after rectifier losses gives me approximately 50VDC).  What I'm missing is how to calculate the VA needed if I know I want 5ADC.

The current is also AC, so is 250VA an rms thing, or a peak thing?  How does the RMS of the current come into play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good reference is [this](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf) Hammond guide.

If you are using full wave rectification from a single secondary, you will need a transformer of 5/0.62 * 36 = 290VA. If you are using a large filter capacitor to minimize the ripple, I would go a bit higher to be safe, maybe 350-400VA.

In a full-wave rectifier-capacitor situation the current from the transformer is drawn in brief sharp pulses at the peak of each half cycle of the mains. The current is mostly limited by the dv/dt of the secondary voltage into the filter capacitor and by the resistance of the secondary winding plus the  dynamic resistance of the rectifiers. Since the peaks are relatively high, the RMS current is quite a bit higher than the average.

Heating of the transformer windings is related to the RMS current, not the average.

Comment: What does the peak and average voltage mean there?  In the full wave bridge rectifier with capacitor, these two values seem to differ quite a bit.  Is average related to loading? Or just ripple?  Is the choke and capacitor more efficient, due to loading the transformer more evenly across the cycle?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it loads the transformer more evenly, but mains-frequency chokes are heavy and expensive. Average is the mean (absolute) value over one mains cycle. RMS is the square root of the (square of the current averaged over one cycle). Peak is the maximum absolute value (during a cycle for the steady state- will be more at turn on). Imagine you turn on a 100 W 100V heater for 1 second then off for 99 seconds. Peak current is 1A. Average power is 1W. Average current is 10mA. RMS current is 100mA. Check I^2*R to see this.

Comment: Fun historic note on choke-capacitor power supplies. In the 1930s, not only were mains-frequency chokes expensive, so were big permanent magnets. So it was normal practice to wind the choke on the loudspeaker, such that the filtered DC current also produced the speaker's magnetic field...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Aka "Dynamic speakers". Back when you couldn't burn things out just by shorting something- oh, the pentode plate is glowing red- must be something wrong.